# Slick slider show 2 image asNavFor option

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I'm using slick slider and i want to show two images in main slide. I added images in slider nav when i click any nav item, it is showing in main slider but only 1 image. how do i add two images.. 
Here is [website link](http://lily-jean.weblicioussolutions.com/product/kiana-maxi-wash-dress/)
here is my js code.

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

Comment: this may helps you :
https://jsfiddle.net/kyL49ygm/

Comment: @BharatBhatiya  interesting solution, let me try this.